# Multiple ASPxGridView's triggering UpdatePanel Not Working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am current trying to use an UpdatePanel containing two ASPxGridView controls and a small form. However, I am running into a few issues. I have configured 2 of these gridviews with the same settings, with respective data sources and events. Where this breaks is when I am using the 'SelectionChanged' event of the gridviews inside the update panel as a trigger to do an AsyncPostback.

The real mystery, is when I have one of the gridviews 'EnableCallBacks' property set to 'True', so that it won't use the update panel, the other one updates perfect. However, if I set both of these properties to false, allowing both of them to update the panel, it breaks. But, it breaks in a weird way. When I go in and select anything it just locks up and doesn't update anything for 90 seconds(which I htink is the default timeout).

Is there any reason you cannot have 2 ASPxGridviews in the same update panel with the respective triggers set to update the panel when the 'OnSelectionChanged' event is fired? If not, are there any other settings other than 'SettingsBehavior-ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer' that need to be setup for the gridviews to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you should set ASPxGridView.EnableCalbacks to false when embedding grid inside UpdatePanel. Here is [general discussion](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18387.aspx) about concept of callbacks in DevEx components.
As for this particular problem it is hard to tell without code but these examples could be relevant for your problem:
1. [How to reload grid data when navigating the TreeList](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E934.aspx)
2. [FocusedRowChanged event and AJAX UpdatePanel](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E83.aspx)

Also, you could implement this without UpdatePanel if those grids are only elements you need to refresh during callback.